# Setting value to non DB attribute while fetching documents from Mongo using Morphia

Tags: java, orm, morphia

This is one sample document (row) from a collection (table) called `product` which is in MongoDB:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb39171528a28f831f"), 
    "seller" : "Product Seller 1", 
    "title" : "Product Title 1", 
    "price" : "159.75", 
    "brand" : "Product Brand 1", 
    "productId" : NumberInt(247)
}
```

The Java Model for this collection looks like this:

```
@Entity(value = "product", noClassnameStored = true)
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Property("_id")
    private ObjectId objectId;

    private String seller;
    private String title;
    private String price;
    private String brand;
    private Long productId;
}
```

I am using Morphia as a MongoDB Java Driver here. And I am using the Lombok @Data annotation which provides the constructor, getters and setters.

The model works perfectly and is able to fetch data from the DB. My new requirement is to add an additional field in the model. The name of the new field would be `stringObjectId`, which will store the value of the `objectId` in String format.

Please note that there will not be any changes in the DB document. That is, no new field is getting added to the DB document.

I want that when I am fetching data from the collection in the form of list or a single row
`query.asList();`

 the value in the `stringObjectId` should also get populated. Something like this: 
`stringObjectId = objectId.toString()`

No far I have tried to override the setters and the constructor of this model to set the value in the `stringObjectId` variable but nothing seems to work. Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Morphia LifeCycle events: https://www.playframework.com/modules/morphia-1.2.4/lifecycle-def

The `@PostLoad` one will be helpful here. You probably will need `@Transient` as well.

Comment: For those facing the same issue, this is the change I made:
`@PostLoad
  public void settingStringObjectIdValue() {
    stringObjectId = getObjectId().toString();
  }
`
I just added this method in my model.